# Why does this function return 1?

Tags: r

I am modifying a list of data frames with lapply and I forgot to set a return statement, but I'm puzzled by how the output was identified.

Example here:

```
val <- list(data.frame('x'=1:4), data.frame('x'=letters[1:4]))
lapply(val, function(subval) {
  val$flag<-1
})
```

Returns

```
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 1
```

I of course understand I can add the line `val` to the end of my function. But it's a curious thing. Is there any intuition in either how `{` or `$`  or `<-` are working in concert to deliver the 1.

Note the desired code is achieved by writing:

```
val <- lapply(val, function(subval) {
  val$flag<-1
  val
})
```

But this is not the point of the post!

Comment: The code itself is not practical. You are assigning 1 to a flag element of the val object created in the global environment. The arguments passed are not used since the parameter subval is not evaluated in anyway. So why have a lapply if you are not interested in the individual elements of the list? The code you wrote is exactly similar to `lapply(val, function(x) 1)`

Comment: @Onyambu perhaps you're missing the point of my post, I have appended what I consider to be the *correct* code - a thing I use often - in case it helps understand what my question actually is.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused - your function defines a single parameter `subval` but that parameter is not used at all in the function. What is the desired output?

Comment: how is the  called *correct* code  correct? You are repeating the whole list n times where n is the length of the list. Should flag be added to individual list elements or should the list be repeated n times???

Comment: Anyway. R does implicit return. The value of the last evaluated statement will be returned. If the last statement is assignment, then the value of the assignment is returned. eg try `f <- function(x) {a <- 3+x}` now if you run `f(2)` nothing will show up. But if you run `(f(2))` you should get a result that will be returned from the function. Now you could do `b <- f(a)` and check out what `b` is. That is because of the implicit return of R

Answer (score 3):

The reason for this behaviour is because of the implicit return in R: The value of the last evaluated statement will be returned. If the last statement is assignment, then the value of the assignment is returned. Look at the example below

```
 f <- function(x) {
    a <- 3+x
 } 
f(2) # nothing shows up. 
(f(2))# prints the value 5 which is the result of last evaluated statement
[1] 5
```

Thus we could do an assignment and see the results:

```
 b <- f(a)
 [1] 5
```

This is exactly what is happening in your case. The value 1 is returned as it is the result of the last evaluated statement in the function scope